# Database won't get new values with a userform

Tags: sql, excel, vba, mariadb, adodb

I'm currently trying to do a userform that insert the values of his textbox inside a MariaDB database. I don't get any kind of error, however, the values just aren't in the base.

Here is my code at this moment

```vb
Private Sub NouvelleEntree()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Derligne As Integer, i As Integer
Dim Requete As String

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        ConnectionDB
'Stop
  Requete = "SELECT * FROM Produits_Beta"
  rs.Open Requete, oConnect, LockType:=adLockBatchOptimistic
                rs.Fields("Ref").Value = CreateProduct.NewRefProduct.Value
                rs.Fields("Nom").Value = CreateProduct.NewNomProduct.Value
                rs.Fields("Famille").Value = CreateProduct.NewFamilleProduct.Value
                rs.Fields("Marque").Value = CreateProduct.NewMarqueProduct.Value
                rs.Fields("Distributeur").Value = CreateProduct.NewDistribProduct.Value
                rs.Fields("Prix achat").Value = CreateProduct.NewPrixAchat.Value
                rs.Fields("Date Maj").Value = Now()
                rs.Fields("PrixVente").Value = CreateProduct.NewPrixVente.Value
                rs.Fields("Marge").Value = CreateProduct.NewPrixVente.Value - CreateProduct.NewPrixAchat.Value
                rs.Fields("DevisFournisseur").Value = CreateProduct.NewDevisFournisseur.Value
                rs.Fields("Image").Value = CreateProduct.NewImageProduct.Value
rs.Update
rs.Close

CreateProduct.Hide
SelectProduct.Hide

End Sub
```

The useform is called "CreateProduct" as you might guess

**UPDATED**

I was trying to ADD a record, so I made an INSERT, however, I now have a SQL Syntax error.

```vb
Private Sub NouvelleEntree()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Derligne As Integer, i As Integer
Dim Requete As String
Dim guillemet As String

nop = ", "

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        ConnectionDB

  Requete = "INSERT INTO Produits_Beta (Ref, Nom, Famille, _
                 Marque, Distributeur, PrixAchat, DateMaj, _
                 PrixVente, Marge, DevisFournisseur, Image) " & _
    "VALUES (" & CreateProduct.NewRefProduct.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewNomProduct.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewFamilleProduct.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewFamilleProduct.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewMarqueProduct.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewDistribProduct.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewPrixAchat.Value & nop & _
             Date & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewPrixVente.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewPrixVente.Value - CreateProduct.NewPrixAchat.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewDevisFournisseur.Value & nop & _
             CreateProduct.NewImageProduct.Value & ")"
  rs.Open Requete, oConnect, LockType:=adLockBatchOptimistic

rs.Update
rs.Close

CreateProduct.Hide
SelectProduct.Hide

End Sub
```

And I have the error

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.59-MariaDB]You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: If you place a breakpoint (F9) on any of the `rs.Fields(...).Value = CreateProduct.*` assignments, then hover the `CreateProduct.controlname.Value` parts, do the controls have the values you're expecting? IOW is the problem with reading the form's state or writing the values to the recordset / updating the DB?

Comment: They do have the values of my Userform (I'm not entering default values, there is some placeholders)
Also, sorry, I didn't understand the local connexion. I use the same synthax for every connexion so I thought I should just use it as a variable previously declared.

Comment: *I use the same syntax for every connection* - yes, so you make a `Function` that returns a `Connection` object that you consume and close in the procedure that invokes that function. Very different than calling some `Sub` that sets and opens some connection object that's floating around in global scope!

Comment: That said, you're selecting every record from the table, but only updating 1 record, whichever comes up first. Is it a single-record table? If not, how do you know you're updating the correct record?

Comment: I think I see your point. I should make it a function.

I was trying to add something, not update. So I used INSERT INTO but now I have an SQL syntax error.

Comment: After tweaking the formatting of your `INSERT` statement for readability, it appears you have 11 columns defined to be inserted, but you've provided 12 items in the `VALUES` clause. That'd probably be the issue.

Comment: Additionally, you can wrap your `Requete =` statement in `With CreateProduct` ... `End With` to A) reduce the typing (you don't need the `CreateProduct` on every line, just the `.<field name>...` portion), and B) it speeds things up fractionally by not having to dereference the form every time.

Comment: I corrected that to 11 items, still have the same error. Does `WITH & END WITH` works to insert into MySQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the issue.

It was that the VALUES where entered as following

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (exemple1, exemple2)
```

while they had to be inserted as

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('exemple1', 'exemple2')
```

There is my final code :

```vb
Private Sub NouvelleEntree()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Derligne As Integer, i As Integer
Dim Requete As String
Dim guillemet As String
Dim Temps As Date

nop = ", "
TruePrixVente = Replace(CreateProduct.NewPrixVente.Value, ".", ",") 'replace the dot a user can put by a coma so it doesn't mess with operations
TruePrixAchat = Replace(CreateProduct.NewPrixAchat.Value, ".", ",")


    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        ConnectionDB

Requete = "INSERT INTO Produits_Beta (Ref, Nom, Famille, Marque, Distributeur, PrixAchat, DateMaj, PrixVente, Marge, DevisFournisseur, Image) " & _
    "VALUES (" & "'" & CreateProduct.NewRefProduct.Value & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & CreateProduct.NewNomProduct.Value & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & CreateProduct.NewFamilleProduct.Value & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & CreateProduct.NewMarqueProduct.Value & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & CreateProduct.NewDistribProduct.Value & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & TruePrixAchat & "'" & nop & _
             "CURDATE()" & nop & _
             "'" & TruePrixVente & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & TruePrixVente - TruePrixAchat & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & CreateProduct.NewDevisFournisseur.Value & "'" & nop & _
             "'" & CreateProduct.NewImageProduct.Value & "'" & ");"

rs.Open Requete, oConnect, LockType:=adLockBatchOptimistic
```